# I need get all gps locations from one place. Not only the best.

Tags: java, android, gps

I have:
....(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
after 10s, i have this same location/coordinate, but i need new, even if is worse than previous. So i need something to get 100 difrence coordinate from one place. Now work like: 6 first location are difrence, after that, 94 is only one this same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Api does not allow to get source cordinate from module GNNS(gps/glonass/etc), even if we chose 0/1m as parameter of accuracy.

Only that device support that: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/gnss.html

Answer (score 0):

For getting locations use use fused api developed by google.This is the best solution for locations.